# Cross forwarding mail between two users in Postfix?

Tags: linux, postfix, mail-forwarding, aliases

Say I want users A and B to receive each other's mail under Postfix. Is there a way to set this up as root? My first approach hasn't worked. Namely, under `/etc/aliases`, the following:

```
A: A, B
B: B, A
```

causes an understandable forwarding loop.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you're using IMAP and both users are on the same IMAP server, it might be cleaner to have each user subscribe to the other's mail boxes, rather than muck through mail forwarding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give user A and B a different login : C and D.

Then configure A and B to be aliases for both C and D.

To make it clear : A and B wont be real nor virtual users anymore, just aliases.

- A@example.com will redirect all mail to C@example.com and D@example.com
- B@example.com will redirect all mail to C@example.com and D@example.com

C and D will both recieve all mails.

Don't disclose C and D and configure their mail client with A@example.com and B@example.com as their main mail adress : Try to make sure no legitimate mail is written directly to C and D.

Is it what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks, that does it. I was hoping there would be a cleaner approach. It is disappointing that Postfix can't understand the original syntax... Thanks again.